# How to get user input from a bat file in sql server pdw?

Tags: sqlcmd

I want to get user input from a batch file and then use the string entered by the user into a SQL file.

For example, I have a batch file called `test.bat`. When I execute that, I should be prompted to enter a value, and after entering that value it should be used in my SQL file.

How can I do that?

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far. Nobody here will implement the whole program for you.

Comment: I have created a bat file named test.bat as below :-          sqlcmd -v item="%item%" -v cost=%cost% -i test.sql 
sqlcmd -S "172.16.253.72,17001"  -U user -P pdw  -d Master -I C:\Maintenance\test_blocking_backup\test.sql -o C:\Maintenance\test_blocking_backup\output.txt  so when i will run this file it should prompt me for the value of item and cost. but then how can i fetch the value entered bt the user in a variable

Answer (score 0):

You should add at the top of your .bat file these tow lines which read user input for the two parameters you are using

```
set /p item=Enter item: 
set /p cost=Enter cost:
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, but yes i have added these statements in my batch file.

Comment: then, it is not working ?, can you post the whole bat file you are using

Comment: Here you go : sqlcmd -S "172.16.253.72,17001"  -U user1 -P pwd  -d Master -I C:\Maintenance\test_blocking_backup\test.sql -o C:\Maintenance\test_blocking_backup\output.txt

set /p item=Item : 
set /p cost=Cost : 

sqlcmd -v item="%item%" -v cost=%cost% -i test.sql
sqlcmd -S "172.16.253.72,17001"  -U user1 -P pwd  -d Master -I C:\Maintenance\test_blocking_backup\test.sql -o C:\Maintenance\test_blocking_backup\output.txt
pause

Comment: can you post the complete bat file with the two lines added (set /p item=...)

Comment: can i get help over this ?